# Multipass timing out on ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, multipass

I made a multipass server with ssh and it says it timed out. 
I'm using the ipv4 they supplied me, and openssh is already installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful guide on setting up SFTP access on an Ubuntu 18.04 server by Digital Ocean here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04.

I would double check the following:

1. Verify the username and password works. Multipass comes with the ubuntu user, if you added a new user it would be best to verify connectivity
2. Ensure the instance has started (e.g. `multipass list`)
3. Verify openssh is running on the instance

Hopefully this helps get you up and running, if you just need access to the instance (without copying files) you can run `multipass exec machine` and you will be dropped into a shell inside the instance.

Answer (score 0):

It was may caused by the change of IPv4 address.
If you run the `multipass list` command, you may find something similar with the following output.

```
PS C:\Users\Slhmy> multipass list
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
dev                     Running           172.28.88.123    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
                                          172.28.95.47
```

Running `ssh root@172.28.88.123` will meet timeout problem, but `ssh root@172.28.95.47` will not.

The I run `multipass shell dev` and check image's network...

```
root@dev:/etc/network/if-up.d# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.95.47  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.28.95.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe4c:d87e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:4c:d8:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 670  bytes 199807 (199.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 461  bytes 64486 (64.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        ...
```

The address of `eth0` changed. You can get the ssh connection by the new IPv4 but I think it's not a good try because it seems that every time I restart my `dev` system the address changed.

So the right solution should be setting a static IPv4 address or something... But I don't know how to realize it. If somebody know the solution, please tell me.

Thanks a lot.

--------------------------------------------------------New Findings--------------------------------------------------------

According to [Add integration with SSH #1957](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1957) in multipass's repository
it is possible to connect to the instance by `<instance-name>.mshome.net` if using hyper-v.

I have tried this solution and works for me.

PS. Before I start the ssh service, I changed some of the configurations and make it works for me. But I think this may not relate with this problem, because if configuration haven't get gone, ssh should denied the connect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a local user and set `PasswordAuthentication yes` on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

If you have changed, you must need to restart the SSH service by `sudo systemctl restart sshd` or `service sshd restart`